# Storage addresses in the database

Tags: database-design

I also learned that to get a list of tax rates for the territory I need to use the address and possibly a zip code. Is there a unified method for storing a structure of addresses in the database?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and consider what is [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159756) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310540/) or [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Storing & processing address is one of the perennial hard problems of data modeling.

If your user community is limited to one country (USA?) follow the guidelines of that postal authority (USPS?).